# calculation inside a loop does'nt make result

Tags: php

I don't understand exactly why but when I write this function, the loop for doesn' work.

Do you have an idea ?

thank you

`$qty` is make by a customer

`$id` : id of the product

`$products_price` price of the product

```
public function getProductsNewPriceByDiscountQuantity($id, $qty, $products_price) {
  $OSCOM_Db = Registry::get('Db');
  $OSCOM_Customer = Registry::get('Customer');
$QprodutsQuantityDiscount= $OSCOM_Db->prepare('select discount_quantity, 
                                                            discount_customer
                                                      from :table_products_discount_quantity
                                                      where products_id = :products_id
                                                      and customers_group_id = :customers_group_id
                                                      and discount_quantity <> 0
                                                    ');
      $QprodutsQuantityDiscount->bindInt(':products_id', $id );
      $QprodutsQuantityDiscount->bindInt(':customers_group_id', $OSCOM_Customer->getCustomersGroupID());

  $QprodutsQuantityDiscount->execute();

  while ($QprodutsQuantityDiscount->fetch()) {
    $discount_quantity[] = $QprodutsQuantityDiscount->valueInt('discount_quantity');
    $discount_customer[] = $QprodutsQuantityDiscount->valueDecimal('discount_customer');
  }

  $nb_discount = count($discount_quantity); //  
  $n = $nb_discount -1; // 0,1,2 for the table indice
```

// Loop the most important to less important

```
      for ($n; $n < 0; $n--) {
//        print_r('qty : ' .$qty . '<br />');
//        print_r('discount : ' .$discount_quantity[$n] . '<br />');

        if($qty >= $discount_quantity[$n]){
          $new_price = $products_price - ($products_price * ($discount_customer[$n] / 100));
        }
      }
```

Comment: $new_price will be overwritten on every loop iteration.

Comment: What database is this and what database API are you using?

Comment: If this is the MYSQL PDO API then I would say that the query should fail. Test the result of the prepare and the execute

Comment: Are you using `for` loop on `getProductsNewPriceByDiscountQuantity ` function?

Comment: $new_price will be overwritten on every loop iteration as nogad says , try to save the new price in new array or in $discount_quantity array

Answer (score 0):

There the solution i found to resolve the problem

```
  $nb_discount = count($discount_quantity); // dans ton exemple 3 discounts
  $i = $nb_discount -1; // 0,1,2 pour les indices des tableaux de ton exemple

  for ($i; $i > 0; $i--) {
    if($qty > $discount_quantity[$i]) {
      $new_discount_price  = ($products_price - ($products_price * ($discount_customer[$i] / 100))) * $qty;
      break;
    }
  }

  return $new_discount_price;
```